# Updating labels inside dynamically generated StatusStrip

Tags: c#

I have a class with functions to return a status strip based on preferences and conditions elsewhere in the program.  The returned status strip is then added to a form.

If I were using Visual Studio's designer, I'd be able to access labels inside the strip through their names since they are created within the form's class.  With the strip being created in another class, I'm unsure how to get access to labels within the returned strip.

```
//statusStrip is declared as a new StatusStrip() at beginning of this form's class
statusStrip = myStripBuilderClass.GenerateStatusStrip();
this.Controls.Add(statusStrip);
//statusStrip now appears in form with the appropriate labels and such.
```

Assuming there is a label named, say, "mousePosition" in statusStrip, what do I have to do so I can get access to mousePosition.Text?  When using Add() for a strip or strip item, it's not actually adding it to a class, so intellisense won't reflect what things have been added.

Comment: Just derive your own class from StatusStrip.  Now you can add private variables, like one that stores a reference to the label, and add a public UpdateMousePos(Point) method that updates the label.  And you can use it in the designer, dropping it directly from the toolbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like all other Controls the `StatusStrip` has a `Controls` collection and you can access the members by their name.

So if you have a `Label` 'mousePosition' on your `StatusStrip` 'statusStrip' you can set its `Text` like this:

```
statusStrip.Controls["mousePosition"].Text = "my mouse is at home";
```

Obviously you want to have nice names for all Labels etc, but 'mousePosition' sounds like you do..

As for IntelliSense, I'm afraid you'll have to do without its support, though.

Comment: You know the proper way to describe that or have any docs on it?  I've never seen something like an array where you access contents with a string.  I'm assuming it's a feature of the language?

Comment: It is not so much an array with a string accessor but rather a collection with two array accessors. The type is [Control.ControlCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and it has several Interfaces. You can access its Items as Item[Int32] or as Item[String]. You should look up on [Indexers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/6x16t2tx.aspx) which _allow  instances of a class or struct to be indexed just like arrays._ This is also possible for classes you define yourself.

Comment: Thanks.  Never knew about that.
Since I was adding the labels through the Items collection, I can access them through statusStrip.Items[string].Text to do the modifications.

Comment: Indeed. You  will notice [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1865435%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that for the `Controls` collection there is __only a getter__ defined; so, in contrast to a real array you can't __set__ any values this way. But accessing a collection's members by name is really nice.  In your own classes you can decide to implement getters __and__ setters, though.. __If__ you are happy to go this way, you may want to accept the answer..

Comment: @user3740530 : Please consider __accepting__ the answer (by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer below the arrows.) This will not only gain both of us a little reputation; more important: It will mark the question as answered. This helps to keep the site in good shape, so nobody has to check if you still need help..